# Securing liferay portlets with spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, liferay, portlet

I am currently working with a liferay portlets. Spring security is used on the Rendering layer( in jsp pages). However, it is not safe, because my dispatch controllers and services do not have any security/authorization checks.

In my application, Spring-MVC controller receives the request, and passes to the Service Layer. Service Layer builds the result and passes it to the JSP pages. In jsp pages we have the security authorization using spring-security taglibs.

I want to know the following:

1. Best practises regarding implementing authorization for portlets.
2. Which is better choice to implement security either on Dispatch layer or Service layer?
3. How to implement security for dispatch layer or service layer?

Please consider that I have security in my application on use-case bases.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My favorite answer matches here: "it depends".

Here's what it depends on:

Liferay defaults to the *LocalService being without any permission checks - e.g. if you have access to the API, you get to do whatever you want. The remote services however are supposed to check permissions before they delegate the actual execution of a service to the local services.

If you want to use Liferay's permissionChecker (which is readily available and runtime-configurable), you should do this in the non-local service methods. I tend to recommend this, as you'll be able to tap into [Liferay's permissioning system](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/security-and-permissio-4) - and you already have the user identity, roles, memberships etc. managed by Liferay anyway. Create a custom role, grant custom permissions and you have everything configurable at runtime.

Secondly, while you definitely want to check the permissions in the backend services, you'll probably want to do it again on the UI layer: If a user is not allowed to manipulate some object, you don't want to display the button that suggests they can change it, only to get a "permission denied" reply.

That being said, I've never tied spring security (especially the taglibs) to Liferay's permission system.

Comment: Thank you Olaf. As I understood from your response, you are talking about the liferay services. Please correct me If I'm wrong. What I'm interested to get some feed back using spring security annotatin sin my local application services. The spring-portlet-security is already in. Do you have any idea how we can use it in the dispatch layer?

Comment: "it depends"... do you want them to hook into Liferay's permission system? Or should they be completely separate from that one. If you want them to hook into Liferay's permission, I can't provide pointers (as I said). If you want them completely separate from Liferay's permissions system, you can just use them as you're used to do. However, this might also be your exact question where I just opened another possibility with Liferay's permissions.

Comment: Thank you Olaf. Actually I want them to hook into the Liferay's permissions.

Comment: @sajjad This is for a long time ago, but I am new in Liferay (7). Have you found any solution for this? I mean hooking the Spring security into Liferay permissions?